# Can I use multiple spring-boot containers with different JDK versions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker and just started playing around with it. I am working on spring-boot micro-service. I have a total of 5 micro-services and all of them are using JDK 8. I was wondering if I can run some of them with different JDK version e.g, OpenJDK 10. Is this possible to do? If yes how will a specify the dockerfile and docker-compose?

Comment: What prevents you to do that? Just specify different `FROM` for different dockerfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can you use like below:

```
DockerFile:
ARG JDK_Path
FROM $JDK_PATH
//rest of your docker file code
```

Now build you Dockerfile with the following command:

```
docker build --build-arg JDK_PATH=/jdk8.0 image_1 .

docker build --build-arg JDK_PATH=/jdk10.0 image_2 .
```